# SYNTAX error in update statement Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error, oledbdataadapter

i have been working on this code, and im getting This syntax error, Does anybody know whats up?

```
    Dim sql As String                                  
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection               
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter                   
    Dim ds As New DataSet                               


    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = G:\school\Thespellingbee\Resources\Spelling Bee1.mdb"   
    con.Open()                                         
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [Words + Definitions]"         
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)           

    da.Fill(ds, "Words + Definitions")                  
    con.Close()                                         

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)         

    ds.Tables("Words + Definitions").Rows(0).Item(1) = WordTextBox.Text
    ds.Tables("Words + Definitions").Rows(0).Item(2) = DescriptionTextBox.Text

    da.Update(ds, "Words + Definitions") 
    MsgBox("It's working", MessageBoxButtons.OK)



End Sub
```

I know im getting close, but right at the end at the da.update part im getting this problem, im still fairly new to vbasic can anyone help? Thanks :)

---

Ok, so i did what hans has told me to do, but now when i get to the ds.tables section near the end i get this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". The database location is correct, and the textboxes are names correctly, so what could be a null reference?

---

my table does have stuff in, three columns, and 10 rows full of data

Comment: Smells like trouble with that awkward table name.  Try omitting the string from the da.Fill and da.Update calls.

Comment: Does the table `Words + Definitions` have some data or is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work out with spaces that well. `ds.Tables("Words + Definitions")` is null.

You can alias the table name in select query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Words + Definitions] [wd]"
...
da.Fill(ds, "wd")
```

Then access as:

```
ds.Tables("wd").Rows(0).Item(1) = WordTextBox.Text
ds.Tables("wd").Rows(0).Item(2) = DescriptionTextBox.Text
```

Nonetheless, you can always access the table by index.

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1) = WordTextBox.Text
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2) = DescriptionTextBox.Text
```